# Adding event handlers to input fields inside bootstrap table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-table

I am using [bootstrap table](https://bootstrap-table.com/).

My table contains cells that contains input fields.

I try to add event handlers (using jquery) to those input fields but it does not seem to work.

If I add the event handlers to a non bootstrap table it works.

The code below demonstrates the issue. When the user change input fields in the upper table (a bootstrap table), nothing is written to the console.When user change input fields in the lower table (non bootstrap table), a message is written to the console.

How do I add event handlers to the input fields in a bootstrap-table?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  console.log('ready');
  $('#my_table_1').find('input[type="date"]').change(function() {
    console.log('Table 1.Date was changed. Need to check if table is sorted by column C.If so - call the table sort.');
  });
  $('#my_table_1').find('select').change(function() {
    console.log('Table 1.Selection was changed. Need to check if table is sorted by column B.If so - call the table sort.');
  });
  $('#my_table_2').find('input[type="date"]').change(function() {
    console.log('Table 2.Date was changed. Need to check if table is sorted by column C.If so - call the table sort.');
  });
  $('#my_table_2').find('select').change(function() {
    console.log('Table 2.Selection was changed. Need to check if table is sorted by column B.If so - call the table sort.');
  });

});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.6.3/css/all.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-table@1.15.4/dist/bootstrap-table.min.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>

<span>A Bootstrap table</span>
<table id="my_table_1" data-toggle="table" data-sort-stable="true">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th data-sortable="true">A</th>
      <th data-sortable="true">B</th>
      <th data-sortable="true">C</th>
      <th data-sortable="false">D</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>
        <select>
          <option val="112">A</option>
          <option val="2">B</option>
          <option val="356" selected>C</option>
        </select>
      </td>
      <td><input type="date" value="2018-07-22"></td>
      <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>123</td>
      <td>
        <select>
          <option val="1" selected>A</option>
          <option val="2">B</option>
          <option val="3">C</option>
        </select>
      </td>
      <td><input type="date" value="2014-07-22"></td>
      <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>56</td>
      <td>
        <select>
          <option val="1">A</option>
          <option val="2" selected>B</option>
          <option val="3">C</option>

        </select>
      </td>
      <td><input type="date" value="2014-08-23"></td>
      <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>14</td>
      <td>
        <select>
          <option val="1">A</option>
          <option val="2" selected>B</option>
          <option val="3">C</option>

        </select>
      </td>
      <td><input type="date" value="2014-07-23"></td>
      <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<!------------------------------------------------------------------->
<hr>
<span>A Non Bootstrap table</span>

<table id="my_table_2">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th data-sortable="true">A</th>
      <th data-sortable="true">B</th>
      <th data-sortable="true">C</th>
      <th data-sortable="false">D</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>
        <select>
          <option val="112">A</option>
          <option val="2">B</option>
          <option val="356" selected>C</option>
        </select>
      </td>
      <td><input type="date" value="2018-07-22"></td>
      <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>123</td>
      <td>
        <select>
          <option val="1" selected>A</option>
          <option val="2">B</option>
          <option val="3">C</option>
        </select>
      </td>
      <td><input type="date" value="2014-07-22"></td>
      <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>56</td>
      <td>
        <select>
          <option val="1">A</option>
          <option val="2" selected>B</option>
          <option val="3">C</option>

        </select>
      </td>
      <td><input type="date" value="2014-08-23"></td>
      <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>14</td>
      <td>
        <select>
          <option val="1">A</option>
          <option val="2" selected>B</option>
          <option val="3">C</option>

        </select>
      </td>
      <td><input type="date" value="2014-07-23"></td>
      <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.6/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-table@1.15.4/dist/bootstrap-table.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Seems ok to me...

Comment: it is working well.

Comment: I agree that the code snippet work.. @CalvinNunes - did you make any changes to the code ? I can see that in the "working code" the "document ready" block was moved to the bottom of the page. Is that what made it work?

Comment: zero changes, just separated the script from the html to create the snippet here in SO, the code was not modified. You probably are loading your scripts in wrong order then, since here in SO te load is made correctly

Answer (score 1):

u need to add your script at the bottom and not in top of the table html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-GJzZqFGwb1QTTN6wy59ffF1BuGJpLSa9DkKMp0DgiMDm4iYMj70gZWKYbI706tWS" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.6.3/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-UHRtZLI+pbxtHCWp1t77Bi1L4ZtiqrqD80Kn4Z8NTSRyMA2Fd33n5dQ8lWUE00s/" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-table@1.15.4/dist/bootstrap-table.min.css">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <title>sorted table</title>
</head>
<body>

<span>A Bootstrap table</span>

<table id="my_table_1" data-toggle="table" data-sort-stable="true">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th data-sortable="true">A</th>
        <th data-sortable="true">B</th>
        <th data-sortable="true">C</th>
        <th data-sortable="false">D</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
   <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td><select>
                <option val="112">A</option>
                <option val="2">B</option>
                <option val="356" selected>C</option>
            </select>
            </td>
            <td><input type="date" value="2018-07-22"></td>
            <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>123</td>
            <td><select>
                <option val="1" selected>A</option>
                <option val="2">B</option>
                <option val="3">C</option>
            </select>
            </td>
            <td><input type="date" value="2014-07-22"></td>
            <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>56</td>
            <td><select>
                <option val="1">A</option>
                <option val="2" selected>B</option>
                <option val="3">C</option>

            </select>
            </td>
            <td><input type="date" value="2014-08-23"></td>
            <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>14</td>
            <td><select>
                <option val="1">A</option>
                <option val="2" selected>B</option>
                <option val="3">C</option>

            </select>
            </td>
            <td><input type="date" value="2014-07-23"></td>
            <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
</table>
<!------------------------------------------------------------------->
<hr>
<span>A Non Bootstrap table</span>

<table id="my_table_2">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th data-sortable="true">A</th>
        <th data-sortable="true">B</th>
        <th data-sortable="true">C</th>
        <th data-sortable="false">D</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
   <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td><select>
                <option val="112">A</option>
                <option val="2">B</option>
                <option val="356" selected>C</option>
            </select>
            </td>
            <td><input type="date" value="2018-07-22"></td>
            <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>123</td>
            <td><select>
                <option val="1" selected>A</option>
                <option val="2">B</option>
                <option val="3">C</option>
            </select>
            </td>
            <td><input type="date" value="2014-07-22"></td>
            <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>56</td>
            <td><select>
                <option val="1">A</option>
                <option val="2" selected>B</option>
                <option val="3">C</option>

            </select>
            </td>
            <td><input type="date" value="2014-08-23"></td>
            <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>14</td>
            <td><select>
                <option val="1">A</option>
                <option val="2" selected>B</option>
                <option val="3">C</option>

            </select>
            </td>
            <td><input type="date" value="2014-07-23"></td>
            <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
</table>

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.6/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-wHAiFfRlMFy6i5SRaxvfOCifBUQy1xHdJ/yoi7FRNXMRBu5WHdZYu1hA6ZOblgut" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-B0UglyR+jN6CkvvICOB2joaf5I4l3gm9GU6Hc1og6Ls7i6U/mkkaduKaBhlAXv9k" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-table@1.15.4/dist/bootstrap-table.min.js"></script>


    <script>
       $(document).ready(function() {
  console.log('ready');
  $('#my_table_1').find('input[type="date"]').change(function() {
    console.log('Table 1.Date was changed. Need to check if table is sorted by column C.If so - call the table sort.');
  });
  $('#my_table_1').find('select').change(function() {
    console.log('Table 1.Selection was changed. Need to check if table is sorted by column B.If so - call the table sort.');
  });
  $('#my_table_2').find('input[type="date"]').change(function() {
    console.log('Table 2.Date was changed. Need to check if table is sorted by column C.If so - call the table sort.');
  });
  $('#my_table_2').find('select').change(function() {
    console.log('Table 2.Selection was changed. Need to check if table is sorted by column B.If so - call the table sort.');
  });

});
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you please explain why?

Comment: it's ok that u add your custom script at the top but what u did is like all the default script are added at the bottom. so what it basically did is first its execute your custom script and it does not know the boostrap script and also some default scripts. so it alway better to add your custom script after you defined your default script files